# How to change docker's default container name and host alias?

Tags: docker, containers, default, naming

Everytime docker generates a random container name and host alias (a hash) if you do not designate them, which are long and do not make much sense to me, difficult to remember and type.

I hope both the container names and host alias are h1, h2... **by default**. Is it possible (how to) configure that?

**Edit**
Per a docker team member's reply, this is not feasible now.

Comment: That entirely depends what tools you use to start the containers.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running the containers using `docker run` then you can use `--name` to specify container_name and `--hostname` to specify hostname. Example:

```
docker run --name mysql --hostname mysql_server mysql:latest
```

If you are using docker-compose to run the containers, then you can specify the details using

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql_container
    hostname: mysql_host
```